# onChange function not firing with one option in the dropdown

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-analytics

I have three drop down fields, one is pulling list of accounts and another drop down field is pulling the list of properties associated with that account. Once the property is selected, the third drop down is populated.

The second drop down field will get populated when the account value is selected. The third drop down value will get selected when second drop down value is selected.

**Issue:**

I select an account, the second box gets populated with a value. Let's say the value is ABC. My desired selection for second box is ABC, now in order to populate the third drop down, we need select2 function to trigger. So I open the dropdown and select another value and then select ABC again to trigger the function

Explained Visually.

[image]

```
//Account Drop Down

//Sample Values - getAccounts()

[ { createTime: 'xxxxx',
    regionCode: 'SA',
    displayName: 'ABC',
    name: 'accounts/XXXX',
    updateTime: 'xxxx' } ]

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="accountData">Select Account:</label>
  <select id="accountData" style="width: 100%" onchange="select1(this)">
    <? var data = getAccounts () ?>
    <? for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) { ?>
      <option>Select Account</option>
      <option value="<?= data[i].name.split('/')[1] ?>" ><?= data[i].displayName ?></option>
      
    <? } ?>
  </select>

  </div>


//Property Field Drop Down

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="accountData2">Select Property:</label>
  <select id="accountData2" style="width: 100%" onchange="select2(this)">

    <option>Select Properties</option>
  </select>
</div>

//Third Dropdown
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="accountData3">Select Data Streams:</label>
  <select id="accountData3" style="width: 100%" onchange="">

    <option>Select Streams</option>
  </select>
</div>


function select1(e) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ar => {
    
    const select = document.getElementById("accountData2");
    select.innerHTML = "";
    
    if (ar.length == 0) return;
    
    ar.properties.forEach(item => {
      
      const option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = item.displayName;
      option.value = item.name.split('/')[1];
      select.appendChild(option);
      
    });
  }).withFailureHandler(er => {

    alert('This is error:' + er);
    
  }).listProperties(e.value);

}


function select2(e) {

  console.log(`${e.value} was selected.`);


google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ar => {
    console.log(ar)
    const select = document.getElementById("accountData3");
    select.innerHTML = "";
    
    if (ar.length == 0) return;
    
    ar.forEach(item => {
      
      const option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = item.displayName;
      option.value = item.name.split('/')[3];
      select.appendChild(option);
      
    });
  }).withFailureHandler(er => {

    alert('This is error:' + er);
    
  }).listDataStreams(e.value);





}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your whole script and the sample values of `data` of `var data = getAccounts ()`? And, I cannot understand your 2nd question of `Second Issue (With Multiple Properties Associated with one account):`. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I have updated the question above for getAccounts(). For second question, I select an account, the second box gets populated with a value. Let's say the value is ABC. My desired selection for second box is ABC, now in order to populate the third drop down, we need select2 function to trigger. So I open the dropdown and select another value and then select ABC again to trigger the function.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details and added more code.

Comment: Can you please share a sample sheet with the script that you have worked on so we can replicate your concern?

Comment: Do you see results from success handler of `.listDataStreams(e.value);`?

Comment: I have added an explanation visual for clarification.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide your whole script?

Comment: You mean all html and code gs related?

Comment: @Tanaike Here is the script - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vhpejx2Hp5QLlIIM1b3SMx7Ik9gXLUg4sjeEVEnRWJ4/edit?usp=sharing (This file has html and code.gs)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your whole script, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your provided whole script, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
  menu.addItem('Launch Audit', 'showSidebar');
  menu.addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  const html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('audit');
  html.options = getAccounts();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html.evaluate().setTitle('GA4 Audit'));
}

function getAccounts() {
  var accounts = AnalyticsAdmin.Accounts.list().accounts;
  var res = "<option>Select Account</option>" + accounts.map(({ name, displayName }) => `<option value="${name.split("/")[1]}" >${displayName}</option>`).join("");
  return res;
}

function listProperties(accountId) {
  var properties = AnalyticsAdmin.Properties.list({ filter: 'parent:accounts/' + accountId });
  return properties;
}

function listDataStreams(property) {
  var streams = AnalyticsAdmin.Properties.DataStreams.list('properties/' + property);
  var id = streams.dataStreams;
  return id;
}
```

#### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <base target="_top">

  <!-- Custom Styles -->
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 20px;
    }

    h1 {
      line-height: 120%;
    }

    .width90 {
      width: 90%;
    }

    .form-group {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      /* padding: 20px; */

    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="accountData">Select GA4 Account:</label>
    <select id="accountData" style="width: 100%" onchange="select1(this)">
    <?!= options ?>
  </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="accountData2">Select Property:</label>
    <select id="accountData2" style="width: 100%" onchange="select2(this)">
    <option>Select Properties</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="accountData3">Select Data Streams:</label>
    <select id="accountData3" style="width: 100%" onchange="">
    <option>Select Streams</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button id="btn">Export</button>
  </div>

<script>
function select1(e) {
  if (e.value == "Select Account") {
    document.getElementById("accountData2").innerHTML = "<option>Select Properties</option>";
    document.getElementById("accountData3").innerHTML = "<option>Select Streams</option>";
    return;
  }
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ar => {
    const select = document.getElementById("accountData2");
    select.innerHTML = "";
    if (ar.length == 0) return;
    ar.properties.forEach((item, i) => {
      if (i == 0) {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = "Select Properties";
        select.appendChild(option);
      }
      const option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = item.displayName;
      option.value = item.name.split('/')[1];
      select.appendChild(option);
    });
  }).withFailureHandler(er => {
    alert('This is error:' + er);
  }).listProperties(e.value);
}


function select2(e) {
  if (e.value == "Select Properties") {
    document.getElementById("accountData3").innerHTML = "<option>Select Streams</option>";
    return;
  }
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ar => {
    const select = document.getElementById("accountData3");
    select.innerHTML = "";
    if (ar.length == 0) return;
    ar.forEach((item, i) => {
      if (i == 0) {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = "Select Streams";
        select.appendChild(option);
      }
      const option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = item.displayName;
      option.value = item.name.split('/')[3];
      select.appendChild(option);
    });
  }).withFailureHandler(er => {
    alert('This is error:' + er);
  }).listDataStreams(e.value);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

- In this modification, when `showSidebar()` is run, a sidebar is opened on Google Spreadsheet. The flow is as follows.

  1. Values are loaded to the 1st dropdown list of "Select GA4 Account:".
  2. When "Selected Account" of the dropdown list of "Select GA4 Account:" is changed, the values related to the 1st dropdown list are loaded to the 2nd dropdown list of "Select Property:".
  3. When "Select Properties" of the 2nd dropdown list is changed, the values related to the 2nd dropdown list are loaded to the 3rd dropdown list of "Select Data Streams:".
  4. By this, you can select from "Select Streams" of the 3rd dropdown list.
- In this case, even when the response value is only one, the 1st values of the 3 dropdown lists are "Selected Account", "Select Properties", and "Select Streams", respectively. By this, you can select the response value from the dropdown list and the onChange event can be fired.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike. This works perfectly fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Arif Ahmed Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

onEdit is a server side trigger not a client side.  You have an enormous amount of client side events in the browser.  Please check the references below to learn more about them.  Also you will probably like to learn how to use Chrome Dev Tools to assist you in debugging your clientside code.

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [Learning to code](https://www.w3schools.com/)

The only method available  server side on Spreadsheets are the drop downs that at provided via [Class DataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)